MacOS 14.4.1 history command won't search back values set at HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE
when I run history cmd it returns 16 past commands.
my history file has 489 commands in it.
my HIST env vars are:
HISTSIZE=10000
HISTFILESIZE=10000
typing this:
history | grep ssh
returns nothing if its older than 16 or so even though I can see it in the history file ~/.zsh_history.
this behavior is new, as it used to work for entire history file.
Is there anything else I can check or do to get the old behavior back?

https://superuser.com/a/232462/1295710
